# Secure Boot Failed - OS not Valid Ubuntu 13.04 Windows 8 Sony VAIO

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, uefi, vaio, secure-boot

This is an extension of this question:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/363355/failing-to-install-ubuntu-13-04#new-answer

I have wiped the cobwebs out - i.e. I have realized that I wasn't following instructions properly.  I will continue to try to do that.  I have run boot-repair from Ubuntu running from CD.  I can no longer boot to Windows 8 on my Sony VAIO SVF14A15CXB but I am fast losing my concern over this.  I am more concerned that I can't install Ubuntu on the hard disk, so every time I boot up I have to install the wifi and resupply the 16 character wifi password, and I would have to reinstall things like GIMP and video codecs every  time I boot up.

Currently, I have an understanding that I need to get back to BIOS, but I am having a difficult time accomplishing that.  There is an "assist" key and I am randomly pressing that along with the function shifter key and F1 F2 F3 and ctrl.  I DID manage to get to BIOS a couple times and my recollection was that it was the only way I managed to boot from CD.  I thought I toggled "SecureBoot" in BIOS, but now I am not sure.  I know I toggled SOMETHING, and I hope I didn't do the wrong thing  by UNchecking it in boot-repair.

Thanks in advance for getting the time of day from any posters.

Comment: I am looking at this web page now:  http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#linux    with some interesting investigations: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6302926/

Comment: well this is disturbing:  https://us.en.kb.sony.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43059/p/48903,49902,74252,85557/c/65,66/kw/entering%20BIOS  the hot key is F2, and I have been pressing it but it has not been working.  I have been unable to enter the BIOS

Answer (score 1):

To get back into the BIOS, 
1) Shutdown your Sony - power off completely
2) Wait 5 seconds 
3) Press the Assist button - must NOT press the power button at all. 
4) Select "Start BIOS setup [F2] by either pressing the F2 key, clicking with the mouse or using the down arrow then enter button
5) change the bios as desired.

Good luck.